# Is there an implementation of apply in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there an implementation of `apply` in python? Can someone give an example with simple function?

I have already tried this it throws an error

```
dfsub.apply(dfsub,function(x){sum(x))
```

where `dfsub` is a dataframe with two columns a and c which has integer values and i want to know the sum of each row?

Comment: Have you tried [`map(sum, dfsub)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)? Otherwise, what exactly do you expect `apply` to do?

Comment: @tobias_k, It seems like OP is using pandas. See [pandas.DataFrame.apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Comment: @falsetru You are probably right, I do not know `pandas` that well. But in this case the question is ill-worded, as OP seems to know the `apply` function, just not exactly how to use it.

Comment: @user3226869, If you mean pandas DataFrame, please tag the question with `pandas`.

Answer (score 4):

Simply pass [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> dfsub = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'c': [4,5,6,7]})
>>> dfsub
   a  c
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
3  4  7
>>> dfsub.apply(sum)
a    10
c    22

>>> dfsub.apply(sum, axis=1)
0     5
1     7
2     9
3    11
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Should be `dfsub.apply(sum, axis=1)` since OP asked for row sums

Comment: @JaminSore, I'm not sure what exactly OP want. But added one that you suggested. Thank you for comment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you were trying to define a function "in-line", using the Javascript syntax:

```
dfsub.apply(function(x){sum(x)})
```

(Note that since we are calling a method, `dfsub` is already implicitly passed.)

Even if that worked in Python, it would have to explicitly `return` the value. But we do not have inline functions with braces. Instead, we have `lambda`s:

```
dfsub.apply(lambda x: sum(x))
```

This is an *expression*, which is why there is no `return`.

That said, in the current case, there is no need for any of that. `sum` is already just the thing we need to pass, as shown in @falsetru's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what `apply` is supposed to do, but I think you are looking for the [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function.

```
In [1]: dfsub = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
In [2]: map(sum, dfsub)
Out[2]: [3, 7, 11]
```